# Adding and Deleting a record using Access VBA and SQL with Recordsets

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to go through my forms checkboxes and If True, I need to check to see if the record exists and then, If it exists and True - Do Nothing.  If True and Doesn't exist - Add the record.
If False - I also need to check if it exists and If it exists - Delete it, and If it doesn't - Do nothing.

I have tried using just recordset and looping through the table.
I also tried using DLookup and just got lost with needing three criteria values to find the record.
Now I am trying to use both recordset and SQL and keep getting the error "too few parameters".

```vb
 RT = "Rise Time"     

 If Me.RiseTime.Value = True Then
 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Weekly_StartTime_Challenges WHERE UserID = '" & 
           Me.UserID.Value & "' AND WeekNumber = '" & Me.WeekNumber.Value 
           & "' AND StartTimeAction =" & RT
 Set sast = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not sast.EOF And sast.BOF Then
        ' It Does Exist and Do Nothing
    Else
        sast.AddNew
        sast!WeekNumber = Me.WeekNumber.Value
        sast!StartDate = Me.StartDate.Value
        sast!UserID = Me.UserID.Value
        sast!FullName = Me.FullName.Value
        sast!Index = 1
        sast!Tab1 = 8
        sast!StartTimeAction = RT
        sast.Update
    End If
 Else
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Weekly_StartTime_Challenges WHERE UserID = '" & 
Me.UserID.Value & "' AND WeekNumber = '" & Me.WeekNumber.Value & "' AND 
StartTimeAction = RT"
Set sast = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not sast.EOF And sast.BOF Then
        ' It Does Exist and needs deleted
        sast.Delete
    Else
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I doubt _Weeknumber_ is text, and what value holds _RT_?

Comment: Same with *UserID*. Is it text?

Answer (score 0):

Do it step by step. For example if you want to check if a record exists:

```
If DCount("ColumnName", "TableName", "ID = 4") = 0 Then
  MsgBox "No Record Found"
  'Do stuf
Else 
  MsgBox "Record/Records found"
  'Do other stuf
End If
```

If you find a record/s you can loop through it with a recordset:

```
Dim rs As RecordSet
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Table", dbOpenDynaset)

rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF

  If "You want to Update the record" = True Then      'Apply your update condition
    rs.Edit
    rs.ID = 4                 'Change ID
    rs.Name = "New Name"    'Change Name
    rs.Update
  Else
    'Do other stuf
  End If

  rs.MoveNext

Loop

rs.close
Set rs = Nothing
```

For changing a datarow you need always recordset `rs.Edit` and in the end `rs.Update`.